# Create dynamic word document using php and html

Tags: php, html, pdf, ms-word

How to create dynamic word document using PHP and HTML, there are only some examples i found in online those are based on header("") based. There are many api in GIT HUB for PDF using php like DOMPDF etc... but i cannot find an worthful api for WORD. Can anyone suggest me!!!!

Comment: use `PHPWord` simple and practical `https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord`

Comment: PHPWORD is like a programming have to design based on the library